# Passing facebook session to service (SDK 3.0.1)

Tags: android, facebook

I have a main activity and a service where i update some data taken from facebook in background every x hours.

In these days i'm finally moving to the new SDK 3.0.1 (from 2.x) and i have a problem with passing the facebook Session to the service:

If the service runs when the main activity is still running everything works fine, otherwise my session is null and so it crashes at if (session.isOpened()) { ...} because session==null.

here's my code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("ServiceUpdate", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

    session = Session.getActiveSession();

    startservice();
    return START_STICKY;
}


private void startservice() {

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {         
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                if (isOnline()) {
                    Log.i("ServiceUpdate", "start timer");

                    update();

                    Log.i("ServiceUpdate", "end timer");
                }
             }

    }, 600000, 6 * 3600000);

}
```

Do i have to initialize the session with saved acces_token and expire_time as I used to do with SDK 2.x ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior for Session is to save the token information in Android's SharedPreferences, so you should be able to just call Session.openActiveSessionFromCache in your service. If that returns null, then that means your user hasn't connected with Facebook yet.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much this way it works even when my activity is not running.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to correct my comment:
This way i get a working session in my Service, but it becomes the new active session so the session in my MainActivity becomes closed. 
Is it possible to have two active and opened sessions in the same time one in my MainActivity and the other in the Service?
With SDK 2.x it was possible and easy... maybe I have to pass the access_token as I did before...

Comment: The active session is a static singleton instance being kept inside the Session class. For your use case, I would first check to see if Session.getActiveSession is null (in both service and MainActivity), and then create a new active session if it is.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I ended up doing. Thank you